# nest function into object more cleanly

Tags: javascript

I successed nested object such as A.

```
  var A = {};
  A.dog = function(){
    console.log("LOVE HUMAN");
  }
  A.dog.say = function(){
    console.log("Woof woof!!");
  }
  A.dog.favorite = {};
  A.dog.favorite.meat = function(){};

  A.dog();
  A.dog.say();

  >>console: LOVE HUMAN
             Woof woof!!
```

next, i tried to write object like B for cleanly.

```
var B = {
    dog:function(){
        console.log("LOVE HUMAN");
      },
    dog:{
      say:function(){
        console.log("Woof woof!!");
      },
      favorite:{
        meat:function(){}
      }
    }
 };

  A.dog();
  A.dog.say();

>>console: TypeError: B.dog is not a function
```

but i failed because of the way of writing.
How can the same thing as A be realized by B's writing style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Object.assign`

```
var B = {
  dog: Object.assign(
    function() {
      console.log("LOVE HUMAN");
    }, {
      say: function() {
        console.log("Woof woof!!");
      },
      favorite:{
        meat: function() {}
      },
    }
  ),
};
```

B.dog();
   B.dog.say(); both will work.

Note: Object.assign is a ES6 javascript feature u can use this [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill)(adds support to all browsers) by adding this script